# Bypassing ambiguity between 2 classes

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I've downloaded TVersionInfo VCL from official web site of Rad studio and installed it successfully in my IDE as they appeared in my toolbox palette. Pasted it in my project and tried first time to build it. I was sure that it'll build ok as I have ran the test project that comes with it. There was OK. 
  But in my project during compilation there were errors. Due to the use of Fib plus package for interbase db access connection it all happened to me.
Here are the errors that appeared in messages:

```
Checking project dependencies...
Compiling Invoice.cbproj (Debug configuration)
[BCC32 Error] VersionInfoUI.h(24): E2015 Ambiguity between 'TVersionInfo' and 'Ib_services::TVersionInfo'
  Full parser context
    main.cpp(10): #include about.h
    about.h(11): #include D:\CB2010_VCL\VersionInfo\VersionInfoUI.h
    VersionInfoUI.h(11): class TCustomVersionInfoLabel
[BCC32 Error] VersionInfoUI.h(25): E2015 Ambiguity between 'TVersionInfo' and 'Ib_services::TVersionInfo'
  Full parser context
    main.cpp(10): #include about.h
    about.h(11): #include D:\CB2010_VCL\VersionInfo\VersionInfoUI.h
    VersionInfoUI.h(11): class TCustomVersionInfoLabel
[BCC32 Error] VersionInfoUI.h(39): E2015 Ambiguity between 'TVersionInfo' and 'Ib_services::TVersionInfo'
  Full parser context
    main.cpp(10): #include about.h
    about.h(11): #include D:\CB2010_VCL\VersionInfo\VersionInfoUI.h
    VersionInfoUI.h(11): class TCustomVersionInfoLabel
[BCC32 Error] about.h(16): E2015 Ambiguity between 'TVersionInfo' and 'Ib_services::TVersionInfo'
  Full parser context
    main.cpp(10): #include about.h
    about.h(13): class TfAbout
Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:04.0
```

I think FIB IB Service class has also the same class name so there is a conflict between two class names. How to fix this? how to make two classes work together like using namespace or smth else?

Comment: do i need to include `class PACKAGE TVersionInfo : public TComponent` in a namespace like `namespace MyVerInfo{ ... } and use MyVerInfo::TVersionInfo` ?

Comment: trying smth like `#if defined (VersionInfoComponentH)
namespace verinfo{
#endif` but no effect!

Comment: any need to change their class names so far? prefixing MyTVersion?

Answer (score 1):

Delphi-generated .hpp files for VCL components are wrapped in namespaces.  The problem is that they also tend to use `using namespace ...` statements at the bottom of them to dump everything into the global namespace, which defeats the purpose of using namespaces at all.  If you look at the bottom of such .hpp files, you will see `#ifdef` statements that show you which values you can define in your project to disable this behavior.  The alternative is to not use `TVersionInfo` at design-time at all.  Create it dynamically in your run-time code instead via the `new` operator, then you can specify which namespace it comes from.

Comment: it seems the only file that has namespace is `versioninforegistration.cpp` the contents looks like           `namespace Versioninforegistration
{
  void __fastcall PACKAGE Register(void)
  {
 const UnicodeString ComponentPaletteLocation = L"VersionInfo";
    //`

Comment: no success with creating it in runtime using code. Because when I include its include files, say, #include "VersionInfoComponent.h" it has class definition and again errors.

Comment: you may check it out, the repository's here: http://radstudiodemos.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/radstudiodemos/branches/RadStudio_XE/CPP/VCL/VersionInfo/

Comment: I'd better use japanese lightweight class comes from Bluewater. Working good.